# How does a list work in SOAPUI Groovy?

Tags: groovy, soapui

After clearing, when adding values to list this is not initializing/emptying the list, however, taking the previous list data.

Groovy code as follows:

```
--Groovy Test Script: 
    def list_2 = []
    list_2.clear()
    log.info list_2
    log.info list_2.add("a1") //adding 1st value
    log.info list_2.add("z2") //adding 2nd value
    log.info list_2.add("x3") //adding 3rd value
    log.info list_2.add("d4") //adding 4th value
    log.info list_2
    log.info list_2.sort()
```

https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source/how-does-LIST-work-in-SOAPUI-Groovy/m-p/152923

So here how come both sorted and unsorted list values are same?

Answer (score 1):

If you want `list2` to be sorted after calling `sort()` on it, you need to pass an argument telling it to modify the list in place.

```
list2.sort(true)
```

Otherwise, `sort()` returns a new list that is sorted.

```
sortedList2 = list2.sort()
```